# Symfony2 : how to check if a file input is empty

Tags: file-upload, symfony

I am making a form to edit an entity where the user can upload a file. When he make some edits, I want to check if he uploaded another file to know if I have to delete the other. I can't find how to know if the input file is empty or not. How can I do this?

Comment: did you try using jquery to validate input file??

Comment: Jquery is useless here, I need to check it in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
      // this is the condition where you can get to know that the value of
      // input field is null or not
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    unset($this->file);
}
```

Check the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)